# Getting Black Image on server side after posting through Json parsing

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, base64

thanks in Advance.. 
In my app, i have to upload an image to the server, below is my code. code is working properly, as i get the response but problem is that, on server side image is just black.

```
sessionid=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"SessionID"]objectAtIndex:0];
  NSLog(@" ID = %@",sessionid);

NSData *da = [NSData data];

da = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.Profilepic);
 NSString *imgStr = [da base64Encoding];
 NSLog(@" %d", imgStr.length);
  NSString *serverscriptpath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://c4ntechnology.com/biker/web_services/ws_insert_register3.php?"];
    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"profile_pic=%@&sessionid=%@",imgStr,sessionid];

    NSLog(@"post string is :%@",post);


    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSLog(@"post length is :%@",postLength);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

    NSString *script_path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",serverscriptpath];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:script_path]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSLog(@"%@",script_path);

    NSData *serverReply = [NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString* responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:serverReply encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSDictionary *dict = [responseString JSONValue];

    NSLog(@"%@",dict);

    [self ReceivedResponse:dict];

    -(void)ReceivedResponse:(NSDictionary *)d
     {
     [AlertHandler hideAlert];
      NSLog(@"%@",d);
     }
```

please any one can help me to find out problem, that why on server image is black.?
 i am using NSDatAdditions.h file for converting into base64.

when i am using

```
       NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Profilepic, 1.0);
```

at server side, file is not supported occurring, so i used

```
       NSData *da = [NSData data];
       da = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.Profilepic);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead of `NSASCIIStringEncoding` (unless you're sure that the web-server uses ASCII encoding).

If this doesn't work, I'd try the followings:

1. Encode image as base 64, and afterwards decode it and check if the result is ok.
2. If 1 passes, check exactly what the server receives (should be the same base64 string as you've sent, otherwise there's probably an issue with different encodings)

As a side note, `da = [NSData data];` is useless, since you overwrite it right after, use directly `NSData *da = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.Profilepic);`

Comment: thank you.. i tried NSUTF8StringEncoding instead of NSASCIIStringEncoding , but its not working, giving same black image.
can u tell me how to decode base64?

Comment: since you have this method `base64Encoding`, I'm presuming you're using this category: https://github.com/WideTag/WideNoise-iOS/blob/master/WideNoise/Categories/NSData%2BBase64Encoding.h

Comment: either way, you should have a method `+ (NSData *) dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *) string;`. So you can use `[NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:imageString];`. The point is to make sure you are sending the correct data, and encoded properly.